# Getting memory leak while creating PDF from webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, memory-leaks

I am having memory leak in while creating pdf from loaded webView. Piece of code for creating PDF via `UIWebView` is written below:

```
- (NSData *)pdfDataForWebView:(UIWebView *)webView {

    UIViewPrintFormatter *formatter =  webView.viewPrintFormatter;
    formatter.startPage = 0;
    UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    [render addPrintFormatter:formatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

    CGRect page;
    page.origin.x = 0;
    page.origin.y = 0;
    page.size.width = 612;//792;
    page.size.height = 792;//612;

    CGRect printable = CGRectInset(page, 30, 30);
    [render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:page] forKey:@"paperRect"];
    [render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printable] forKey:@"printableRect"];

    NSMutableData * pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, page, nil);
    for (NSInteger i=0; i < [render numberOfPages]; i++) {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
        [render drawPageAtIndex:i inRect:bounds]; //***--Memory-Leak-***
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    NSString *pdfFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/mcsweb.pdf"];
    [pdfData writeToFile:pdfFile atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"pdf file %@", pdfFile);
    return pdfData;
}
```

I have found leak via leak instrument but don't know how to resolve it. While using break point break point stuck with that particular line for 10 to 20 times for pdf of just 2 pages, then executes rest code.